# How do I avoid repeating the same values of a group in the next group within the same column variable? (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have categorised `PRODUCT_TIME` to `CATEGORY` as below:

```
structure(list(EPISODE = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), PRODUCT_TIME = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
6, 8, 10, 1, 2, 1, 5, 8, 2), CATEGORY = c("1", "2", "1", "1", "2", 
"3 to 5", "3 to 5", "3 to 5", "3 to 5", "6 to 10", "6 to 10", 
"6 to 10", "1", "2", "1", "3 to 5", "6 to 10", "2")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L))

   EPISODE PRODUCT_TIME CATEGORY
     <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>  
 1       1            1 1      
 2       1            2 2      
 3       1            1 1      
 4       2            1 1      
 5       2            2 2      
 6       2            3 3 to 5 
 7       2            4 3 to 5 
 8       2            4 3 to 5 
 9       3            5 3 to 5 
10       3            6 6 to 10
11       4            8 6 to 10
12       4           10 6 to 10
13       4            1 1      
14       4            2 2      
15       4            1 1      
16       4            5 3 to 5 
17       4            8 6 to 10
18       4            2 2
```

What I want to do is based on the `CATEGORY`:

1. find out how many distinct values of `EPISODE` in each `CATEGORY`, then
2. also exclude the `EPISODE` value in the next grouping if they had had already occurred in the previous group from the `CATEGORY` column.

`CATEGORY` is an ordered variable as "1", "2", "3 to 5" and "6 to 10"

I generated `CATEGORY` using the `cut` function which worked well for me but I did not know how to proceed further, and `n_distinct()` works nicely to find out how many distinct values of `EPISODE` are in each group within `CATEGORY`, but I've no idea how to exclude any `EPISODE` values that have occurred in the previous group of `CATEGORY` and then do `n_distinct()`.

So what I want to get is something along the lines of this summary (i.e. printing the number of distinct `EPISODE` values per `CATEGORY` if distinct from the previous group on `CATEGORY` is sufficient):

```
GROUP "1" = 3 distinct EPISODE values (1, 2 and 4)
GROUP "2" = 0 distinct EPISODE values
GROUP "3 to 5" = 1 distinct EPISODE values (3)
GROUP "6 to 10" = 0 distinct EPISODE values
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks! I am stumped...

Comment: Maybe `xtabs(!duplicated(EPISODE) ~ CATEGORY, df[order(df$CATEGORY), ])` - assuming you want results by the factor order of `CATEGORY`.

Comment: @lotus your solution is the most elegant! How do I select this as the best answer?

Comment: @lotus Also as I am fairly new to R, could I ask- what is the rationale of doing `df[order(df$CATEGORY)]` - I don't know what it means to put the dataframe outside of the function. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "manufactured" way with tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate(CATEGORY, c("START", "b", "END"), remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(END = coalesce(END, START)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(SEQUENCE = list(START:END)) %>% 
  unnest(SEQUENCE) %>% 
  group_by(CATEGORY) %>% 
  summarise(distinctEpisode = toString(sort(unique(EPISODE)))) %>% 
  separate_rows(distinctEpisode, sep = ", ") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(first_occurrence = if_else(duplicated(distinctEpisode), 0, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(distinctEpisode = if_else(first_occurrence == 0, 0, as.numeric(distinctEpisode))) %>% 
  summarise(distinctEpisode = toString(distinctEpisode), .by = CATEGORY) %>% 
  mutate(distinctEpisode = str_remove_all(distinctEpisode, "0,\\s|0, 0|, 0"))
```

```
  CATEGORY distinctEpisode
  <chr>    <chr>          
1 1        1, 2, 4        
2 2        0              
3 3 to 5   3              
4 6 to 10  0
```

addition:
adding this line:

```
  mutate(result = paste0(str_count(distinctEpisode, ",") + 1, " distinct EPISODE values (", distinctEpisode, ")"), .by = CATEGORY, .keep = "unused")
```

will result in:

```
 CATEGORY result                             
  <chr>    <chr>                              
1 1        3 distinct EPISODE values (1, 2, 4)
2 2        1 distinct EPISODE values (0)      
3 3 to 5   1 distinct EPISODE values (3)      
4 6 to 10  1 distinct EPISODE values (0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is saved in object `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df$CATEGORY <- factor(df$CATEGORY)
split_df <- group_split(df, CATEGORY)

EPI_l <- map(split_df, ~ distinct(.x, EPISODE) |> 
               pull(EPISODE))

EPI_l <- c(NA, EPI_l)[-(length(EPI_l) + 1)]
  
res <- split_df |> 
  map2(EPI_l, ~ filter(.x, !EPISODE %in% .y)) |> 
  list_rbind() |> 
  count(CATEGORY, EPISODE)    

res
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  CATEGORY EPISODE     n
  <fct>      <dbl> <int>
1 1              1     2
2 1              2     1
3 1              4     2
4 3 to 5         3     1
```

---

EDIT: In case I misunderstood

```
res |> 
  summarize(num_episodes = n(), 
            EPISODE = paste(EPISODE, collapse = ", "), 
            .by = CATEGORY) |> 
  mutate(num_episodes = if_else(EPISODE == "NA", 0, num_episodes))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  CATEGORY num_episodes EPISODE
  <fct>           <dbl> <chr>  
1 1                   3 1, 2, 4
2 2                   0 NA     
3 3 to 5              1 3      
4 6 to 10             0 NA
```

Or perhaps

```
res |> 
  summarize(num_episodes = n(), 
            EPISODE = paste(EPISODE, collapse = ", "), 
            .by = CATEGORY) |> 
  mutate(num_episodes = if_else(EPISODE == "NA", 0, num_episodes),
         CATEGORY = paste0('GROUP "', CATEGORY, '" = '),
         result = paste(num_episodes, "distinct EPISODE values", if_else(EPISODE == "NA", "", paste0("(", EPISODE, ")"))) |> 
           stringr::str_trim()) |> 
  select(CATEGORY, result) |> 
  as.data.frame()

            CATEGORY                              result
1       GROUP "1" =  3 distinct EPISODE values (1, 2, 4)
2       GROUP "2" =            0 distinct EPISODE values
3  GROUP "3 to 5" =        1 distinct EPISODE values (3)
4 GROUP "6 to 10" =            0 distinct EPISODE values
```

Comment: I think the output is not correct! Look at category!

Comment: It's not clear to me if OP just gave a rough indication of what they're looking for (what I assumed), or they want the output to look exactly as shown.

Comment: You’re right Phil , don’t care about how the out put looks :)

Comment: Please mark as solved which ever solution answers your problem. @Jobolo

Comment: hi thanks!  @lotus solved my issue with one line of code (see thread below my OP) :) thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

This could simply be solved using recursion

```
unq <- unique(df$CATEGORY)
vals <- setNames(rep(list(integer(0)), length(unq)), unq)

fn <- function(dat, vals){
    if(!nrow(dat)) return(vals)
    group <- dat$CATEGORY[1]
    vs <- unique(dat$EPISODE[dat$CATEGORY == group])
    vals[[group]] <- vs
    Recall(dat[!dat$EPISODE %in% vs,], vals)
}

fn(df, vals)
$`1`
[1] 1 2 4

$`2`
integer(0)

$`3 to 5`
[1] 3

$`6 to 10`
integer(0)
```

---

Note that if you are only interested in the lengths, change the part `vals[[group]] <- vs` to `vals[[group]] <- length(vs)`. And use a vector for vals instead of a list. Or simply calculate the length after you obtain the values. ie:

```
lengths(fn(df, vals))
 1       2  3 to 5 6 to 10 
 3       0       1       0
```

---

If you need it in dataframe format:

```
rev(stack(lengths(fn(df, vals))))
      ind values
1       1      3
2       2      0
3  3 to 5      1
4 6 to 10      0
```